# Can someone recommend a podcast that consists of book readings?

Tags: radio

I have near-native fluency, and am just looking for a steady stream of fiction read aloud.

I am familiar with Lectures Du Soir from Radio France, but it seems to be discontinued and I can only play it on my phone's Radio France Podcast App, which is surprisingly not user-friendly. The readings are broken down into 5 minute sections . It has no playlist and I have to manually play the next episode, which takes about 2 buttons and 4 taps. Really annoying when you're in the bath.

I have a podcast app that is great, and that searches itunes and it finds many radio france podcasts, but not Lectures Du Soir.

I'm also familiar with https://librivox.org, which has many audio books, but these are mostly over 100 years old...

Hoping someone can point me at some great stories that are read aloud, that keep coming... :)

Answer (score 2):

[France Culture offers other fictions](http://fictions.franceculture.fr) as podcast, albeit often episodic. You can find them on their website, of course, but on [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/artist/france-culture/id729430130?mt=2)* as well. Your favourite podcast app should be able to play them for you, you don’t have to rely on the Radio France app at all.

* Or is it only available in France? I hope not. Still, you should have access to the RSS feeds on the France Culture website.

Comment: This was not easy to find, but le voila: http://radiofrance-podcast.net/podcast09/rss_13023.xml